# Comparing previous row values in Pandas DataFrame with Condition

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare value of row col1 with previous row and my script is working fine, however I would like to add another condition to compare rows col1 if rows col3 is same as previous one, so that row col1 on index 13 will not be compare with index 12 as their are not same value on col3

```
    import pandas as pd
    data1 = {'col1': [10, 30, 11, 24, 22, 50, 12, 10, 30, 31, 32, 33, 20, 41, 44], 'col3': [
        'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AB', 'AC', 'AC']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=['col1', 'col3'])
    print(df)

    col1 col3
0     10   AB
1     30   AB
2     11   AB
3     24   AB
4     22   AB
5     50   AB
6     12   AB
7     10   AB
8     30   AB
9     31   AB
10    32   AB
11    33   AB
12    20   AB
13    41   AC
14    44   AC


    df['col2'] = df['col1'].gt(df['col1'].mul(2).shift())
    print(df)

    col1 col3   col2
0     10   AB  False
1     30   AB   True
2     11   AB  False
3     24   AB   True
4     22   AB  False
5     50   AB   True
6     12   AB  False
7     10   AB  False
8     30   AB   True
9     31   AB  False
10    32   AB  False
11    33   AB  False
12    20   AB  False
13    41   AC   True
14    44   AC  False
```

Comment: What's the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expected output is not fully clear. If you want to have False where the condition of equality on col3 is unmet:

```
df['col2_alternative1'] = (  df['col1'].gt(df['col1'].mul(2).shift())
                           & df['col3'].eq(df['col3'].shift()) )
```

If you want to have  (boolean NA):

```
df['col2_alternative2'] = (df['col1'].gt(df['col1'].mul(2).shift())
                             .mask(df['col3'].ne(df['col3'].shift()))
                             .astype('boolean')
                          )
```

output:

```
    col1 col3   col2  col2_alternative1  col2_alternative2
0     10   AB  False              False               <NA>
1     30   AB   True               True               True
2     11   AB  False              False              False
3     24   AB   True               True               True
4     22   AB  False              False              False
5     50   AB   True               True               True
6     12   AB  False              False              False
7     10   AB  False              False              False
8     30   AB   True               True               True
9     31   AB  False              False              False
10    32   AB  False              False              False
11    33   AB  False              False              False
12    20   AB  False              False              False
13    41   AC   True              False               <NA>
14    44   AC  False              False              False
```

Comment: thanks your alternative1 code solve my issue where i want only to compare value within same group order in col3

Comment: @Lukman If you're often working with groups, you might also be interested in `groupby` ;) This would be needed if the rows were not sorted by group and you wanted to compare to the previous value of same group

Comment: in our case we have first sort order the data and applying comparison and thanks of an idea of groupby, so far havent playing with it and need study :)